# Serving dynamic webpages using Hunchentoot/html-template/Lisp

Tags: lisp, web-applications, hunchentoot

The following code using Hunchentoot and html-template was allowing me to serve dynamic webpages up until recently when I upgraded Hunchentoot to the latest version.  Can someone please suggest where I have gone wrong with the code below?  I assume the problem is in the macro definition?

```
(defmacro define-url-fn ((name) &body body)
  `(progn
     (defun ,name ()
       ,@body)
     (push (create-prefix-dispatcher ,(format nil "/~(~a~).html" name) ',name) *dispatch-table*)))

(define-url-fn (sign-up)
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (let* ((values (list :username-error-msg *register-error*)))
      (fill-and-print-template #p"/ELEPHUND/INTERFACE/sign-up.tmpl" values :stream stream))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had some trouble with Hunchentoot after the upgrade to version 1.2.0.  If you're instantiating an object of class acceptor, as I was, you may need to change it to use the class easy-acceptor instead.

```
(push (make-instance 'easy-acceptor) *acceptors*)
```

Then you can continue to use `create-prefix-dispatcher` as before.